# How to specify a specific Windows Event Application log for logging from SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I'm new to SSIS packages but want to set up process logging to the Windows Event Log. Is there a way to specify an event log other than the general windows application log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The default 'SSIS log provider for Windows Event Log' will only log to the Application log.

Your alternative is to create a custom log provider.

Comment: In my searches around the internet and asking more knowledgeable colleagues, this seems to be the consensus.  Does anyone know of a good online tutorial specifically targeted at creating a customized windows event log provider?  Most I've found seem focused on text file logs of some flavor.